# R: use ifelse for data.frame?

Tags: r

how to use ifelse statement or other to solve like-this **by one line code**:

```
data[which(data > 2,arr.ind = T)] = 2.0  
data[which(data < -2,arr.ind = T)] = -2.0
```

or

```
data2 = data
data2[which(data > 0,arr.ind = T)] = "A"  
data2[which(data <= 0,arr.ind = T)] = "B"
data = data2
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and show what the desired output should look like.

Comment: Hi @ryster, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [follow these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9406040) to edit your question in a way that makes it possible for us to help you.